# Error: Output routine didn't use all of \box255

Tags: beamer, errors, output

I get this error message for my footer:

```
\begin{textblock*}{0.9cm}(3.5cm,9.25cm)
\raggedleft
{\usebeamercolor[fg]{title in head/foot}\usebeamerfont{title in head/foot} 
\hspace*{10cm}{\textbf{IEB}\hspace*{0.5cm}\insertframenumber}}
\end{textblock*}

%\hspace*{0.5cm}

\begin{textblock*}{3cm}(2cm,9.25cm)
{\usebeamercolor[fg]{author in head/foot}
\usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor}
\end{textblock*}

%Nombre del curso
\begin{textblock*}{7cm}(-0.9cm,9.25cm) 
\raggedleft
{\usebeamercolor[fg]{title in head/foot}
\usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}  \titulo \insertshorttitle}
\end{textblock*}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. How or where is the `textblock*` environment defined?

Comment: As always on this site please provide a full but minimal self contained examples, not out of context sniplets like this.

Comment: you probably have some outdated files somewhere (probably textpos is not new enough). Check for updates. If this doesn't help, show a complete example.

Comment: Textblock* is defined here:

Comment: How can i show you an example?

Comment: Textblow* is defined in a file named: beamerouterthemeuniud. May i send you what i have?.If you send me an email, i will send all files i have

Comment: No please make a small but complete example that shows the problem then edit the code block in your question to have that example. The code you show currently can not be used so doesn't help anyone help you.

Comment: `textblock*` is likely defined by the package `textpos`. I am currently suffering from the same problem.

Comment: Hello. Can anybody help me?